# Bootstrap 3.3.7 .Img-thumbnail border makes image dissappear on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-sprites

I have a rather strange issue where the 1px border added to the img-thumbnail class in bootstrap is making my **image disappear on mobile phones**. Removing this
my image appears fine. Also if I try using a smaller sized image it works.

The image in question is a sprite of logo images. So, you guys can see what I mean I have recreated the issue on codepen:

[Codepen of issue](http://codepen.io/vishpatel93/pen/aJqveg?editors=1100)

html Code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 midxssm col-sm-4 col-md-2"><img class="img-18001 img-circle img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADIAQMAAACXljzdAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABxJREFUeNrtwYEAAAAAw6D5U1/hAFUBAAAAAHwGFFAAAcRa5isAAAAASUVORK5CYII="></div>
```

Here is a screengrab from my Samsung Galaxy s5 showing how the image doesn't show:

[image: mobile view]

Bootstrap 3.3.7 img-thumbnail css:

```
.img-thumbnail{display:inline-block;max-width:100%;height:auto;padding:4px;line-height:1.42857143;border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:4px;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out}
```

**Update:**

After more debugging, this works on the Iphone 5s using the safari browser and on the Samsung Galaxy S5 using the default browser. Just looks to be an issue with Chrome on the Samsung Galaxy S5 and default browser on the Samsung Galaxy S6.

Clicking 'Request desktop site' makes it works accordingly. But, otherwise not. Why could this be ?

Tried on numerous devices. Including chrome on S6 to no avail. Clearing cache will show background colour on first load then back to blank white hereafter.

Tried with a different image and it works. The image it won't work with is a sprite image that is 200px width by 7200px height and the image that it will work with is an image that is 208px width by 2,080 height. But with the first image removing border css makes it work. What is going on?

**Update 21/03/17**

I have updated the codepen adding various dimension images and if you look through it a pattern emerges whereby images above 4096 pixel height will not show with the .img-thumbnail class. Falling inline with the maximum supported chrome mobile browser image dimension of 4096 pixels.

> **I could therefore split my original sprite image into two or three smaller images and not hit the threshold, but I would like to know
>   what correlation does the border have regarding this issue. Why does
>   removing the border from img-thumbnail make it work ? even if the
>   sprite size is above maximum ?**

Comment: i can't replicate the issue. I can see the image just fine on lower width.

Comment: @hunzaboy works fine when testing on other devices, juts when I am testing on mobile phone

Comment: Working fine on my mobile

Comment: APAD14 I just tested on safari on an iphone 5s and it works. But, on the Samsung Galaxy s5 using chrome it won't

Comment: Most likely an issue with the device, not with the code.

Comment: Tried on numerous devices. Including chrome on S6 to no avail. Clearing cache will show background colour on first load then back to blank white hereafter

Comment: Add your update as an answer - the issue seems a platform specific (Chrome Mobile) issue however it may help others experiencing the same issue.  BTW I believe adding a 1px border to the image adds 2px to the display size of the image - therefore 4096 is interpreted as 4098px...

Comment: @Mauro I will most definitely provide an answser once I can sufficiently understand the end issue.  I get that, but my first sprite is 7200 pixels in height, way above the 4096 px threshold, but only thing seem to be stopping it is the 1px border.

Comment: Looking elsewhere on the internet I found the following link on an HTML 5 Game Dev site(http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/14319-sprite-sheet-maximum-size/) `there are maximum sizes to textures.`. 
It references` WebGL Stats site` (http://webglstats.com/webgl2/parameter/MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE?platforms=0000007c0012800500).  

I wonder if adding a border to your image may be forcing the browser to use a rendering component (such as WebGL) that is limited to 4096px

Comment: @Mauro we seem to have reached the same point. Came across exact same thing this morning. I think possibly webGL is being triggered by the border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking elsewhere on the internet I found the following link on an `HTML 5 Game Dev site`([html5gamedevs.com/topic/14319-sprite-sheet-maximum-size‌](http://html5gamedevs.com/topic/14319-sprite-sheet-maximum-size%E2%80%8C)​)

> there are maximum sizes to textures..

It references the `WebGL Stats site` ([webglstats.com/webgl2/parameter/…](http://webglstats.com/webgl2/parameter/MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE?platforms=0000007c0012800500)). I wonder if adding a border to your image may be forcing the browser to use a rendering component (such as WebGL) that is limited to 4096px ?

Comment: I have replied in the comment to your comment, which is a direct version of this

Comment: @VaishalPatel the idea is comments are potentially transitory - they could be deleted or moved to chat, this is a copy of the "answer" comment.  I've made the answer a community wiki so i don't gain rep from it.  Feel free to add more to it.

Comment: I am currently reading into it all. I have a suspicion the border causes a resize, which then is causing a repaint. Not sure yet